# Ubuntu automatically sends SIGTERM to the running processes

Tags: oom

I'm using `foreman` (ruby gem) to start 10 worker processes at once. This makes the `system` send `SIGTERM` to the main `foreman` process.

Although, when I try to run 9 worker process, everything works fine.

I don't think OOM killer is acting up here as each process is around 250mb and I have
1 GB residential, 3 GB swap.

Any idea what would be causing this issue?

PS: `foreman` uses `open3` to start the processes.